# OLE Automation in Delphi: Find out line number of selection

Tags: delphi, ms-word, automation, ole

is there a way to use the OLE Automation in Delphi (with TWordApplication of Unit Word2000) to search for a string in a Word Document and then give back the Line Number of the beginning of the selection? I already figured out how to search in a Word document though.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to get the absolute line number is playing with selection, ranges and iterating over all the lines until the beginning of the document, which is pretty inefficient.  Do you really need the line number?

Comment: Hi, well it would be nice to have the line number, yes. Is there an other way to get it over the Selection.Information or so?

Comment: The line number is difficult to get for a reason. It changes frequently (for instance, when the margins or font size or tab widths change, text is added/deleted). If you do the search, and before you can use it the user changes any of those things, your line number may be invalid. Perhaps if you told us what you're actually trying to do, there might be a better way to accomplish it than with line numbers.

Comment: @user1578813 it would be nice is not the kind of enough motivation to write this.  If you are ok with what you have now, it is ok for me. :)